# jquery this child selector?

Tags: jquery, parent

hey,
quick question, i couldn't find anything on the web. I have a parent div and a child div inside of it. to select it with css you would say:

```
#parent .child {}
```

In jquery I have a var for my parent element, however how can i select the child with this?
I know it's easy to create a new var, i'm just curious if it's possible?

```
var Parent = $('#parent');

Parent.click(function() {
$(this > '.child').hide();
```

thank you

Comment: Note that the [selector `E F`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) matches not just child elements but *any* descendant element of `E`. For the children only use [`E > F`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
$(".child", this)
```

If you only want the *direct* children:

```
$("> .child", this)
```

(credit goes to *Gumbo* for mentioning this)

*Update, two years later*:

You can use `$(this).find('> .child')`

Answer (score 6):

You may just invoke the `.find()` method:

```
var Parent = $('#parent');

Parent.click(function() {
    $(this).find('.child').hide();
});
```

If you only want to select the immediate children, use the `.children()` method instead:

```
Parent.click(function() {
    $(this).children('.child').hide();
});
```

People often use a syntax like

```
$('.child', this);
```

aswell. It's not very convinient to me since you write a "reverse" order someway. Anyway, this syntax gets converted internally into a `.find()` statement, so you're actually saving a call.

Ref.: [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
  $("#parent").click(function () {
               $(this).next().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Parent = $('#parent');

Parent.click(function () {
    $(".child", this).hide();
});
```

or

```
$("#parent").click(function () {
    $(".child", this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

U can find children of your parent elements and apply css.

***Sample code is below.***

```
var Parent = $('#parent');

Parent.click(function() {
$(this).find('.child').hide();});
```